# Flutter + Global var or SQL?

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter

So I need to have a few things store in either a var that is accessable by all widgets. or store things in a SQL and then get the widgets to check for the latest update.

Task I am trying to do.

I have 3 images at the bottom of my main_widget.dart each one when clicked on does the following:

1. Stop the current radio station music.
2. Start the radio station that the user click on.
3. Changes the now playing url to match the station. - this is a separate widget all together.

So can flutter do global var that store or should I use SQL and store the values in a table called

active:

- Station URL
- Station Now Playing URL

And then call this when the user opens and closes the app as well as when the user clicks on another station logo just update the active database to have the correct data?

Answer (score 1):

Having SQL or any database kind method is not good for just make it available from all widgets. There is no need basically. You need some kind of global variable but of course there are better ways than global variables.

The concept is called state management. [Start reading from official flutter website.](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)

I recommend BLOC for most cases. Here is the main website of a good BLOC package for flutter apps. Created by Felix Angelov. https://bloclibrary.dev/#/

For saving the simple user data for closing/opening the app you can use [shared preferences.](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) But be aware it is not for storing sensitive data like tokens, credentials etc. Just use it for "simple" and "non-sensitive" data.

Comment: So with BLOC if I have 3 images with say stationURL, NowplayingURL how do I pass them to the BLOC? Sorry the examples on that page are like for counting up and down. Thats not what I need.
@Mansur

Comment: You need to adjust it to your needs. There are plenty of examples around the web. I think you can find better examples.